# problem in switching next activity in list view on android

Tags: android, android-layout, android-listview

in my app `i use list view with setonclickListener`. if i try go next activity by click a image button i get `android your content must have a listview whose id attribute is 'android.r.id.list` error, in my next activity i have text view and video view(in xml). the error in ddms point out the next activity oncreate().

my first activity xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
  <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="100dp"                  android:descendantFocusability="blocksDescendants">
   <image view>....</image view>
   <LinearLayout android:orientation="vertical"    android:descendantFocusability="blocksDescendants"
     <ImageButton android:id="@+id/imageButton1 ... ></ImageButton>
    <ImageButton android:id="@+id/imageButton2 ... ></ImageButton>
    <ImageButton android:id="@+id/imageButton3 ... ></ImageButton>
 </LinearLayout> 
</RelativeLayout>
```

logcat:

```
 06-10 16:00:23.526: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(3857): Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Your content must have a ListView whose id attribute is 'android.R.id.list'
06-10 16:00:23.526: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(3857):     at android.app.ListActivity.onContentChanged(ListActivity.java:236)
06-10 16:00:23.526: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(3857):     at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.setContentView(PhoneWindow.java:201)
06-10 16:00:23.526: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(3857):     at android.app.Activity.setContentView(Activity.java:1622)
06-10 16:00:23.526: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(3857):     at com.exercise.AndroidList.videoview.onCreate(videoview.java:11)
06-10 16:00:23.526: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(3857):     at  android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1047)
```

videoview is my next activity. please help me.

Comment: Can you post code of activities?

Comment: thanks i give extends ListActivity in next activity. i remove that it work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your second activity is a ListActivity it needs a layout that contains a ListView element with android:id="@android:id/android:list", if your second activity is not a ListView it should not extend ListActivity.

Comment: thanks i give extends ListActivity in next activity. i remove that it work